# How to export zoomable PDF from ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-10.2, pdf, zoom

I have a basemap layer of a country and I want to create a PDF where I can zoom in and see the basemap in more detail. The same way as when I zoom in ArcGIS.

Is it possible to export such PDF from ArcGIS?

I tried to higher the resolution, but it's not working.

Comment: export to ai (illustrator) and use either gimp/inkscape or Adobe Illustrator to create a high res zoomable map in vector format. If your base map is raster it will be only as high as that raster dpi.